# Project running on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web application that configured to run using IIS , but I don't have IIS currently installed on my machine and i don't want to change it

so can any one tell me how to change the .csproj file to run on the development server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you All for your help , I have found it , I edit the .csproj file , and change

```
<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
```

to

```
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

Your project in Solution Explorer -> Right-Click -> Properties -> Web

Select "Use Visual Studio Development Server" option.

Save settings. Build and run your web application.

Or you can edit your .cproj file manually:

- Open it in text editor
- Find <WebProjectProperties> section ( most probably at the end of file)
- Change **<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>** option to **<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>**
- Save your file

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which version of Visual Studio you are using, but in VS2010, you right click your project, choose properties, go to the "Web" tab and finally check the "Use Visual Studio Development Server" radio button.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Klausbyskov for your answer , I'm using VS2008 , and the project is unavaliable , and I can't edit it's properties